# Loop wire connected to a voltage source and Induced voltage

Tags: electromagnetism

I know that an induced voltage in a loop wire is caused by a changing external magnetic field, or changing surface of the loop wire, or a combination of both. But in my script I have the following example.

In an ideal but open conductor loop at which the ends (’1’ and ’2’) are at two different potentials (caused by a voltage source), the induced voltage is calculated as follows:
$$V_{ind}=\int_{(F)}\vec{E}(\vec{r}, t)\cdot d\vec{r}= \int_{(F)'}\vec{E}(\vec{r}, t)\cdot d\vec{r} +U_{12}, $$
where $V_{12}=\int_{1}^{2}\vec{E}(\vec{r}, t)\cdot d\vec{r}$.

I have two questions:

1. Why do we have an induced potential in the wire that is already connected with a  voltage source?
2. Can anyone explain me the logic behind the above expression?

Edit:
In the ideal conductor with an infinitely high conductivity, the electric field disappears. The induced voltage is thus $V_{ind}=V_{12}$.

I understand that the electric field is inverse proportional to the electric conductivity. But is there a physical explanation as to why higher electric conductivity means weaker electric field?

**Symbol definitions:**

$V_{ind}$ is the induced voltage (potential difference in the wire).

$(F)$ is the contour of the wire.

$\vec{E}(\vec{r}, t)$ is the position and time dependent electric field inside the wire.

$V_{12}$ is the potential difference that comes directly from the voltage source.

Comment: I find it (almost) impossible to answer you question because I do not know what a number of your symbols refer to. Please define your symbols and the terms in your equation.

Comment: I did, define them

Comment: Many things in this long question are wrong and show confusion, maybe try asking a simpler question.

Comment: I mean, I am simply copy pasting what is given in my script. Cannot do better then this